# Make Javas Nashorn ScriptEngine behave like a console

Tags: java, scripting, nashorn

I've got a Java game engine with an in-engine debug console that uses Javas Scripting feature, using JavaScript as the scripting language.

I want the scripting engine to behave like a Javascript console would, like the one in the Chrome inspector. So explicitly, when i enter a statement like

`4 + 4` or `world.getDayTime()` or `redrawTerrain()`

i want to see the output by default, instead of having to enter

`print(<the statement>)`

A makeshift solution to this is to surround all inputs with `print()`, but that fails once you declare variables or enter anything that isn't a statement.

Can you change the verbosity or "display mode" of the scripting engine? If not, how does Chrome / Firefox / Rhino CLI do it in their consoles?

Comment: Isn't there a return value from eval()? Just print it from the Java side.

Comment: @glee8e Man i feel dumb, that does it, thank you. Whenever there's a statement it returns an `Object` which you can just turn into a string if it isn't null. I changed the writer of the engine via the context and i thought that was all the output it had.

Comment: OK, I shall post a answer and let this be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various `ScriprtEngine.eval()` methods all have a return value. Just somehow stringfy it and print it to the desired output, e.g. STDOUT or ingame console.